# Glassfish memory leak?

Tags: glassfish, flash, memory-leak

I have been developing a flex application and noticing that my Glassfish server seems to be using more and more memory each time I tested the application.

Specifically, it seems that to take more memory each time it runs .java files that query from SQL database (just select). Even though, it's basically the same operation it seems that after I test my application for 30+ times it stopped responding and I have to restart the server.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Check for an increasing number of applications that don't exit, using PS and/or TOP for the web server user. Also check for any one process that keeps getting bigger.

Comment: Sorry but what are PS and TOP? I'm still a newbie when it comes to java server.

Comment: Unix shell commands. Top shows you all the running processes and the CPU and basic memory info while ps shows you the specific process status.

Comment: I'm using Windows and the task manager says that java.exe uses 50% of CPU and 500+ MB of RAM.

It starts with 70 MB of RAM and slowly increases until it hits 500+ then the app slows down drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved: By re-writing .java each time query is made factory manager still stays on the server so I have to close it after I use it.